# populate google chart datatable with arrayToDataTable in django template

Tags: python, django, google-visualization

I have a list of tuples passed to the template.
I want to populate a datatable with it.
Here is the code. 
Does anyone know what is wrong with it? Currently nothing shows on the webpage.
Thank you.

```
    var dt=new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Name','LastGPA','CurGPA','IntervalA','IntervalB','Major'],
    {% for d in data %}
    [{{d.0}},{{d.1}},{{d.2}},{{d.3}},{{d.4}},{{d.5}}]
    {% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    ]);
    summary_table.draw(dt);
```

Comment: Open the page in a browser, view source, and paste the relevant javascript so we can see what that code is producing.

Comment: +1 @asgallant. Also, I'm pretty sure it's because you don't have a comma at the end of the line for the 2D array you're building.

Comment: @JeremyFaller, there is a comma, produced on the line `{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}`.

Comment: Hi. I used another approach. But I still don't know the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [helper module](https://gist.github.com/flibbertigibbet/5637627) for using the Visualization API with Django queries.  You might find it easier to work with passing JSON, rather than building it in the template.